# Get Members Group for discussion list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, event-receivers, email, groups, discussion-board

I am trying to develop custom alerts for a SharePoint Discussion List(in Community sub-site), I want to mail these alerts only to people in Members group of the Community (only those who have Joined the community ) how can I get these Members in Event receiver using Server side(C#) coding. I have managed to iterate the SiteGroups but how can i make sure that which one among the is Members and not Visitors/Owners Group.

Comment: SPWeb.AssociatedMemberGroup https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.associatedmembergroup.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In code you can

```
SPGroup spGroupItem = web.Groups["GroupName"];
SPRoleAssignment oRoleAssignment = web.RoleAssignments.GetAssignmentByPrincipal(spGroupItem);

foreach (SPRoleDefinition inRole in oRoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings)
{
        //inRole.id //inRole.Name
        //1073741829 //limited access
}
```

Or you can find it using below function

```
bool IsMemberGroup(string groupName) 
{
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite("<your site collection>"))
    {
       using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
       {
          foreach (SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment in web.RoleAssignments)
          {
              if (roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Contains(web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Contributor)))
              {
                 SPPrincipal principal = roleAssignment.Member;
                 if (principal is SPGroup) 
                 {
                    if(principal.Name.ToLower() == groupName.ToLower())
                        return true;
                 }
              }
          }
       }
    }       
    return false;
}
```

Another option is

```
SPWeb.AssociatedMemberGroup
```

Comment: I prefer SPWeb.AssociatedMemberGroup thanks...just an addition in case for future use to this There are properties on the SPWeb class:

SPWeb.AssociatedVisitorGroup
SPWeb.AssociatedMemberGroup
SPWeb.AssociatedOwnerGroup